# Set Content-Type as text/plain using EWS java API

Tags: java, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010, ewsjavaapi

I use EWS Java API to send mails through Exchange 2010. From the trace I find that content type is set as `text/xml`. Is there a way to send mails as plain text only?

> Content-Type: text/xml

Thanks.

Comment: Yes...But i want it to be text only...Is there a way to change it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the communication through that API goes with SOAP calls and these should have `Content-Type=text/xml; charset=utf-8` - without double quotes around `utf-8`. EWS is quirky about that.

I think that is what you are seeing in your trace.

The trick is to set the [BodyType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa565622%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) to *Best* or *HTML* or *Text* whenever you use operations like GetItem, UpdateItem.

Comment: Hi, i modified the Body type as text. I could find the trace <t:Body BodyType="Text"> tag. But it still adds a header with Content-type as text/xml...:(:(

Comment: hi...is there a way to edit the headers added by the EWS API??

Comment: I don't know anything about the EWS Java API, you'd have to 'dive under the hood' as far as you can see code. I'm coding raw SOAP calls from Delphi and there I have full control over the components that handle the HTTP requests/responses. They have an OnBeforePost handler where I can insert stuff like: " HttpAddRequestHeaders(Data, PChar(cContentHeader), Length(cContentHeader), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_REPLACE);  ", with cContentHeader = 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8';